# How to create a vertical line with the same length as the row in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem creating a vertical line that has the same length of a parent row a element in bootstrap3. What I'm trying to do is a row with 3 elements in it. The height of the row depends on the column containing the content. Then I'm trying to create a vertical line in a column but i can't get the column having the same height as the content column.

Here is my code

```css
.col-section{
  background-image: url("../img/small_steps.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  border: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.vertical-line-right{
  background-color: black;
  width: 2px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-left col-section">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="vertical-line-right">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 pull-left">
      <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I used a height of 10px for the height of the vertical line to show you a result whereas i want it to dynamically make the height of the "lorem ipsum" div

The result of the snippet is wrong here is what i really get:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izy1V.jpg

I hope my question is clear enough ! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking is a solution with dynamic height where one element's height adjust itself according to 2nd element, not sure this can achieve only with pure CSS

Made some changes in HTML

put the `col-section` selector inside the `col-md-5` and gave `id="content"` and bind it with jQuery.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 pull-left" id="content">
            <div class="col-section">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="vertical-line-right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 pull-left">
             <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-section {
    background-image: url("../img/small_steps.png");
    background-repeat: repeat;
    border: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
}
.vertical-line-right {
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('document').ready(function () {
   var Height = $('#content').height();
   $('.vertical-line-right').height(Height);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wdog8f0v/1/)

For better approach, `setInterval` so if the page height and width changes, height adjust itself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(borderline,1000);
    function borderline(){
       var Height = $('#content').height();
       $('.vertical-line-right').height(Height);
    }
});
```

[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/wdog8f0v/2/)

Comment: It worked thank you. What if I want to remove the length of the margin bottom from my col-section class? I tried this but this doesn't work:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(borderline,1000);
        function borderline(){
            var Height = $('#content').height() - $('.col-section').css('margin-bottom');
            $('.vertical-line-right').height(Height);
        }
    });   

I m not familiar with jQuery so this might be trivial.

Thanks a lot for your good answer anyway.

Comment: can you update the fiddle in answer with the margin code so I can have look at it and in your attempt of jquery, if you are trying to add margin then it should be like this `$('.col-section').css('margin-bottom', '10px');` and in current code there is no margin in CSS so even I can't guess a proper solution there is only padding: 10px;

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was that it returned a string so i had to parseInt() the result to make the addition after.
Thanks a lot